# Populate mongoose on 3 schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate Schema. I have successfully populate 2 schema. But I have a hard time/understanding on populating 3 schema.

these are my schema

member schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MemberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    full_name : {
        type: String
    },
    current_position : {
        type: String
    },
    position: {
        type: String
    },
    dateStarted : {
        type: String
    },
    is_admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default : false
    },
    team : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Team'
    },
    account : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Accounts'
    }
});

var Members = module.exports = mongoose.model('Members', MemberSchema);
module.exports.createMember = function(newMember, callback){

    newMember.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

account schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Team = require('../model/team');


var AccountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    account_name:{
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    account_type:{
        type: String
    },
    website_url:{
        type: String
    },
    description:{
        type: String
    },
    account_owner:{
        type: String
    },
    phone_number:{
        type: String
    },
    industry:{
        type: String
    }
});

var accounts = module.exports = mongoose.model('Accounts', AccountSchema);

module.exports.createAccount = function(newUser, callback){

    newUser.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

team schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    team_name : {
        type: String
    },
    dateCreated : {
        type : Date,
        default:function(){
            return Date.now();
        }
    }
});

var Team = module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);


module.exports.createTeam = function(newTeam, callback){

    newTeam.save(function(err,teamObj){
        if (err) throw err;
        if(teamObj){
            if(typeof callback == 'function'){
                callback(null, teamObj._id); 
            }
        }
    });

}
```

and this is wnat i already populate, the team schema and member schema

```
[
  {
    "_id": "587f276edebe7725c48e7286",
    "full_name": "joel ralph balignasay",
    "position": "Web Developer",
    "dateStarted": "Nov 15 2016",
    "team": {
      "_id": "587f25a98a583e1954908832",
      "team_name": "Web Team",
      "__v": 0,
      "dateCreated": "2017-01-18T08:22:01.541Z"
    },
    "account": "587f210d7729b13554901cf4",
    "__v": 0,
    "is_admin": false
  }
]
```

this is my function

```
app.get('/admin/accounts/show_team/api/merge', function(req,res){
    var team_id = '587f25a98a583e1954908832';
    var account_id = '587f210d7729b13554901cf4';
    MemberModel.find({}).populate('team').exec(function(err,member){
        Accounts.find({}).populate('account').exec(function(err,acount){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.json(member);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks. I just want to know how to insert the account schema.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I already found a way this is my updated function

```
app.get('/admin/accounts/show_team/api/merge', function(req,res){
    var team_id = '587f25a98a583e1954908832';
    var account_id = '587f210d7729b13554901cf4';
    var member_id = '587f276edebe7725c48e7286';
    MemberModel.findById(member_id)
        .populate('team')
        .populate('account')
        .exec(function(err,results){
            res.send(results);
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even limit the fields you want after population, like this

```
app.get('/admin/accounts/show_team/api/merge', function(req,res){
    var team_id = '587f25a98a583e1954908832';
    var account_id = '587f210d7729b13554901cf4';
    var member_id = '587f276edebe7725c48e7286';
    MemberModel.findById(member_id)
        .populate('team', 'teamField1, teamField2, teamField3..')
        .populate('account', 'accountField1, accountField2...')
        .exec(function(err,results){
            res.send(results);
        })
});
```

_id always comes by default.
If you only want _id, do this

```
app.get('/admin/accounts/show_team/api/merge', function(req,res){
    var team_id = '587f25a98a583e1954908832';
    var account_id = '587f210d7729b13554901cf4';
    var member_id = '587f276edebe7725c48e7286';
    MemberModel.findById(member_id)
        .populate('team', '_id')
        .populate('account', '_id')
        .exec(function(err,results){
            res.send(results);
        })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, we'll try that